# Python: Subsets of Data with most common entries

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, grouping, subset

I'm struggling hard with following problem.
Imagine, that i have a lot of data like this:

```
one = {'A':'m','B':'n','C':'o'}
two = {'A':'m','B':'n','C':'p'}
three = {'A':'x','B':'n','C':'p'}
```

and so on, which does not have to be stored in dicts necessarily.
How could i get subsets of the data with the most common entries?

In the example above I'd like to get

```
one, two          with same A and B = m,n
two, three        with same B and C = n,p
one, two three    with same B       = n
one, two          with same A       = m
```

Answer (score 2):

One way but not more efficient for long dictionaries is using [*`itertools.combinations`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to find the combinations between your dictionaries then loop over the combinations and then the sets and get the intersection between the set items :

```
one = {'one':{'A':'m','B':'n','C':'o'}}
two ={'two':{'A':'m','B':'n','C':'p'}}
three = {'three':{'A':'x','B':'n','C':'p'}}

dict_list=[one,two,three]
v_item=[i.items() for i in dict_list]

from itertools import combinations
names=[]
items=[]
l=[combinations(v_item,i) for i in range(2,4)]
flat=[[[t[0] for t in k] for k in j] for j in l]  
"""this line is for flattening the combinations i don't know why but python puts every elements within a list :
>>> l
[[([('one', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'o', 'B': 'n'})], [('two', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})]), 
([('one', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'o', 'B': 'n'})], [('three', {'A': 'x', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})]), 
([('two', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})], [('three', {'A': 'x', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})])], 
[([('one', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'o', 'B': 'n'})], [('two', {'A': 'm', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})], [('three', {'A': 'x', 'C': 'p', 'B': 'n'})])]]"""


for comb in flat :
   for pair in comb:
     names,items =zip(*pair)
     items=[i.viewitems() for i in items]
     print names,reduce(lambda x,y:x&y,items)
```

Result :

```
('one', 'two') set([('B', 'n'), ('A', 'm')])
('one', 'three') set([('B', 'n')])
('two', 'three') set([('B', 'n'), ('C', 'p')])
('one', 'two', 'three') set([('B', 'n')])
```

And about the following lines :

```
     items=[i.viewitems() for i in items]
     print names,reduce(lambda x,y:x&y,items)
```

You need to c[reate a `view` object of your items](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) that tread as `set` objects then you can calculate the intersection of items with `&` operand. 
using a [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) function.

Comment: uff, you're right, it's brutally slow on large datasets, plus running out of memory :O :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kasra, that gave me the final hint :).
I changed some things and converted it to Python3 (forgot to mention that...).
But as your code, it is brutally slow and running out of memory on large datasets (which I do have). So that I have to look for another approach :/.

Here is my final code:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

class Piece():
    def __init__(self,tag,A,B,C):
        self._tag = tag
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C

        self._dict = set(self.__dict__.items())  


pieces = []
pieces.append(Piece('one','m','n','o'))
pieces.append(Piece('two','m','n','p'))
pieces.append(Piece('three','x','n','p'))


l=[combinations(pieces,i) for i in range(2,4)]
flat =[]
for i in l:
    for k in i:
        flat.append(k)


for f in flat:
    print('-'*25)    
    print([j._tag for j in f])
    dicts = (i._dict for i in f)    
    matches = reduce(lambda x,y : x & y,dicts)    
    print(matches)
```